# GA4 API and Query Explorer vs Analytics Dashboard Metric and Dimension mis-matched

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to fetch the information using GA4 API and Query Explorer and matching the same with the GA4 Dashboard.
While doing so I am seeing that there is a significant difference in Dimension and Metric Data for the same period of time

Dimension on Query Explorer: New vs Returning

Dimension on GA4 Dashboard: New vs Established

[image: Screen Grab from Query Explorer]

[image: Screen Grab from Dashboard]

Further checking this I found that there is a difference in definition at both the ends

[image: Query Explorer]
[image: GA4 Dashboard]

Link to these definition

[GA4 API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema)

[GA4 Dashboard](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9143382?hl=en)

I am looking for how can get these Dimension and Metric correctly using the API/Query Explorer.

Comment: try using active7DayUsers

Answer (score 1):

There is no new / established dimension in the api.

New vs returning is not the same

[New / returning](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#newVsReturning)

New users have 0 previous sessions, and returning users have 1 or more previous sessions. This dimension returns two values: 'new' or 'returning'.

This might get you close

[7-day active users active7DayUsers](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#active7DayUsers)

The number of distinct active users on your site or app within a 7 day period. The 7 day period includes the last day in the report's date range.

Comment: So I will not be able to get the Dashboard data using API?